# import CSV file with different attributes from a different class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

I need an example on how to import a CSV file with different attributes. So far when I run my code I get an error message saying unknown attribute 'email' for Student. The email attributes can coming from the Parent. Beside importing the attributes for students only and parent only. How can I import parent’s attributes within the student attributes?

My program work find when I exports my CSV with parents attributes in my student program.

Any help would be appreciated.

student model class:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent

  delegate :email,:name,:phone_number,to: :parent, allow_nil: true

         def self.to_csv
            attributes = %w{parent_id email phone_number first_name last_name  age workshop interest registration_date email   }
            CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
              csv << attributes

              all.each do |script|
                csv << attributes.map{ |attr| script.send(attr) }
              end
            end

          end

def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header=spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    #CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      student = find_by_id(row["id"])|| new
      student.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
      student.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    when ".xls" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end

end
```

Student controller:

```
def import
  Student.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "student imported."
end
end
```

view folder:

```
<h2>Import Students</h2>

<%= form_tag import_students_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please provide your code and the error.

Comment: @Uzbekjon i edit my post with the code. thank you

Comment: Could you also add the error stacktrace as well?

Comment: @Uzbekjon the error message is highlighting:  student.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)  app/models/student.rb:69:in `block in import'
app/models/student.rb:65:in `import'
app/controllers/students_controller.rb:15:in `import'

Comment: @Uzbekjon did i post the correct error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to advice you is 'keeping your model code thin'. The best practice is to keep your model to be responsible only for data otherwise it violets [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

```
class ImportStudentsService
  SUPPORTED_TYPES = ['.csv', '.xls', '.xlsx'].freeze
  STUDENT_ATTRIBUTES = %w(
    parent_id first_name last_name  
    age workshop interest registration_date   
  ).freeze

  PARENT_ATTRIBUTES = %w(email phone_number email).freeze

  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
  end

  def call
    import
  end

  private

  def import
    spreadsheet.each do |row|
      student = Student.find_or_initialize_by(id: row['id'])
      parent = student.parent || student.build_parent
      student.attributes = row.slice(*STUDENT_ATTRIBUTES)
      parent.attributes = row.slice(*PARENT_ATTRIBUTES)
      student.save!
      parent.save!
    end
  end

  def spreadsheet
    unless SUPPORTED_TYPES.include?(File.extname(@file.original_filename))
      raise "Unknown file type: #{@file.original_filename}"
    end
    Roo::CSV.new(@file.path)
  end
end
```

In controller

```
def import
  ImportStudentsService.new(params[:file]).call
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "student imported."
end
```

It's not 100% working code but the main idea is presented here.

Comment: I agree with about keeping mu model class code thin, however is it possible to help me with the way I have my program code. can you give me an example on how to import parent’s attributes within the student attributes?

Comment: I defined two constants which keeps student and parents attributes, the mapping is happens here. Thinks example already imports some data to parent model.

Comment: i am getting an error message no implicit conversion of String into Integer when I used your def import method